# How does python's built-in 'all' function work under the hood? Specifically, will it exit after finding the first false?

Tags: python, iterable

Will python's all function exit as soon as it finds a False in the iterable? Or will it continue checking the rest?

For example, if i is not divisible by 20, will the below code continue checking if it is divisible by 19 and 18 and so on?

```
def min_divisible(target_n):
    '''
    Returns the smallest number that is divisible by all integers between 1 and n
    '''
    i = target_n
    while not all((i%j == 0) for j in range(target_n,2,-1)):
        i+=target_n
    return f'{i:,}'

print(min_divisible(20))
```

Answer (score 3):

`all` will stop the iteration as soon as it encounters a "falsey" object.  You can see this with a simple example:

```py
def produce_numbers():
    for k in range(10):
        yield k
        print(k)

all(k < 3 for k in produce_numbers())
```

This prints

```
0
1
2
```

This is spelled out in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=all#all).  It states that the following is a functionally equivalent definition of `all`:

```py
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This is true if you use a lazy generator as a parameter.  But if you use a list comprehension for example, the entire list will be created before the `all` function is called and the early return is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkRansom What does that have to do with `all` and the question and this answer, though?

Comment: I think he’s adding a warning that you won’t enjoy this short-circuit feature if you pass in a list.  That’s a very good tip because I’ve seen a lot of code where this occurs.

Comment: The *"This is true if"* sounds like the "this" (your answer) isnt true if not, though. I.e., that something you wrote is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I didn’t take it that way.

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right, I probably could have phrased that better.  The answer is absolutely correct, but I wanted to point out a common case where that would be a moot point.  You just know somebody's going to be bitten by it, and I'd hate for someone to think they'd been misled.